# Get past 1 hour data using a self join T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, self-join

I have a table like this (claimsTable),

```
 Time              Terminal_ID  Claims data_from
------------------------------------------------

2017-10-19 06:03:00     1        561     2
2017-10-19 06:04:00     1        562     2 
2017-10-19 06:05:00     1        562.3   2
2017-10-19 06:06:00     1        563     2
2017-10-19 06:03:00     9        471     2
2017-10-19 06:04:00     9        471.9   2
2017-10-19 06:05:00     9        472.3   2
2017-10-19 06:06:00     9        473     2
2017-10-19 06:07:00     1        567     1
2017-10-19 06:08:00     1        567.6   1 
2017-10-19 06:09:00     1        568.2   1
2017-10-19 06:10:00     1        569     1
2017-10-19 06:07:00     9        475     1
2017-10-19 06:08:00     9        475.9   1
2017-10-19 06:09:00     9        476.3   1
2017-10-19 06:10:00     9        476.3   1
```

For each ID there is days worth of data. I only showed some data above. Now, I check oldest data for each `Terminal_ID` from `data_from` = 1 like this,

```
select min(Time), Terminal_ID
from claimsTable 
where data_from = 1 
group by Terminal_ID
```

I get `2017-10-19 06:07:00` for each ID.

Next, I check the latest data for each `Terminal_ID` from `data_from` =2 like this,

```
select max(Time), Terminal_ID 
from claimsTable 
where data_from = 2
group by Terminal_ID
```

Now, I get `2017-10-19 06:06:00` for each `Terminal_ID`.

Now, I want to get the 60 mins worth of data from newest time (max(TIME) of `data_from` = 2 to calculate the avg for each hour that is from oldest data that is from `data_from` = 1.

So, I did a check using self join like this,

```
select 
      t1.[Time], t1. Terminal_ID
from 
    claimsTable t1
inner join 
    claimsTable t2
    on t1.Terminal_ID = t2. Terminal_ID
where t1. Terminal_ID = t2. Terminal_ID and 
      t1.[Time] between dateadd(mi,-59,t2.[Time]) and t1.[Time]
```

This does not give me the desired check because I am not using `max` function for `t2` and `min` function in `t1`. I am not sure how to include them when I do a self join.

My expected output table:

```
Time              Terminal_ID  Claims data_from
------------------------------------------------
2017-10-19 06:03:00     1        561     2
2017-10-19 06:04:00     1        562     2 
2017-10-19 06:05:00     1        562.3   2
2017-10-19 06:06:00     1        563     2
2017-10-19 06:07:00     1        567     1
2017-10-19 06:03:00     9        471     2
2017-10-19 06:04:00     9        471.9   2
2017-10-19 06:05:00     9        472.3   2
2017-10-19 06:06:00     9        473     2
2017-10-19 06:07:00     9        475     1
```

How can I check previous 60 mins worth of data from `data_from`= 2 starting the oldest data that is `data_from` = 1?

Comment: The conclusion of all what you say is your **desired outputs**, that's what we need to see in your question please.

Comment: Use Max on t2.time

Comment: Use datediff instead of dateadd and you don't need to join on the whole table, only the columns you need from it.

Comment: so let me get this straight - you want to get all the records between (2.Max_Time - 60 mins and 1.Min_Time) for each terminal? then you want to average the Claims column for each terminal between (2.Max_Time - 60 mins and 1.Min_Time)? - what is data_from by the way?

Comment: @DawoodAwan Yes, correct. You put everything is two lines! data_from is coming from different tables. Because, when new data comes in, I know it comes from 1.

Comment: @i.n.n.m did my query work then?

Comment: @DawoodAwan, yes, it did, i think you were getting Null because not enough data!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to calculate the `Avg` of all records between `mintime(data_from = 1 )` and `(Max - 60 mins AND data_from == 2)`

The thing is that I am getting `NULL` for both cases maybe because something missing in the query - OR not enough data

Try running the query , if any issues let me know.

This is the query with query to create sample data:

```
    -- CREATE SAMPLE DATA
    DROP TABLE #claimsTable

    CREATE TABLE #claimsTable
    (
        [Time] DateTime,
        Terminal_ID INT,
        Claims FLOAT,
        data_from INT

    )

    INSERT INTO #claimsTable
    VALUES

        (N'2017-10-19 06:03:00',     1 ,       561  ,   2),
        (N'2017-10-19 06:04:00',     1 ,       562  ,   2), 
        (N'2017-10-19 06:05:00',     1 ,       562.3,   2),
        (N'2017-10-19 06:06:00',     1 ,       563  ,   2),
        (N'2017-10-19 06:03:00',     9 ,       471  ,   2),
        (N'2017-10-19 06:04:00',     9 ,       471.9,   2),
        (N'2017-10-19 06:05:00',     9 ,       472.3,   2),
        (N'2017-10-19 06:09:00',     9 ,       473  ,   2),
        (N'2017-10-19 06:07:00',     1 ,       567  ,   1),
        (N'2017-10-19 06:08:00',     1 ,       567.6,   1), 
        (N'2017-10-19 06:09:00',     1 ,       568.2,   1),
        (N'2017-10-19 06:10:00',     1 ,       569  ,   1),
        (N'2017-10-19 06:05:00',     9 ,       475  ,   1),
        (N'2017-10-19 06:08:00',     9 ,       475.9,   1),
        (N'2017-10-19 06:09:00',     9 ,       476.3,   1)
```

I change 1 or 2 times in the sample data to get a better understanding of the results my query was generating

The actual query begins here:

```
    Select
        A.TerminalId,
        Avrg = AVG(data_between.Claims)
    From
        (
        -- this inner query returns
        /*
            TerminalId  |           MaxTime (data_from == 2)    |   Min Time (data_from == 1)
            -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            9           |   2017-10-19 06:09:00.000             |   2017-10-19 06:05:00.000
            1           |   2017-10-19 06:06:00.000             |   2017-10-19 06:07:00.000
        */

            Select
                TerminalId = data_from_2.Terminal_ID,
                MaxTime2 = MAX(data_from_2.[Time]),
                MinTime1 = data_from_1.[Time]

            From
                #claimsTable data_from_2
                -- This will get MIN the data_from = 1 for each terminal_id
                CROSS APPLY (
                    SELECT TOP (1) 
                        * 
                    FROM #claimsTable  a

                    WHERE a.data_from = 1 AND a.Terminal_ID = data_from_2.Terminal_ID

                    ORDER BY a.[Time] ASC

                ) data_from_1
            --
            Where data_from_2.data_from = 2
            -- group by to get the Max.Time for each terminal
            GROUP BY data_from_2.Terminal_ID, data_from_1.[Time]
        ) A

        -- join with claimsTable again to get the data between mintime(data_from = 1 ) and (Max - 60 mins) so we can calculate avg

        LEFT JOIN #claimsTable data_between on data_between.Terminal_ID = A.TerminalId AND data_between.[Time] BETWEEN A.MinTime1 AND DATEADD(MINUTE, -60, A.MaxTime2)
        --
        GROUP BY A.TerminalId
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the max function on the time column from the self join.

```
select 
      max(t2.[Time]), 
      t1.Terminal_ID
from 
    claimsTable t1
full join 
    claimsTable t2
    on t1.Terminal_ID = t2. Terminal_ID
    and t2.time <= dateadd(mi,-59,t1.[Time]) 
group by
    t1. Terminal_ID
```

Comment: I didn't understand this part `t2.time <= dateadd(mi,-59,t1.[Time]) ` in inner join.

Comment: sorry, that should have been a full join @i.n.n.m but what it does is create a a cartesian product which is then limited to a single row using max. on clause you are asking about will join every row where the time is 60 minutes or greater, and then find the max of that subset

Comment: @scsimon I think the `LEFT JOIN` becomes a `FULL JOIN` now. :)

Comment: I need to check if there is 60 mins worth data starting the latest record of `data_from` =2. So, it is actually something like from that point going back to about 60 mins timestamps. Your answer gives the latest in `t1`, which is `2017-10-19 06:11:00 ` for each Terminal_ID

Comment: Well you haven't given an expected output so that's hard to decipher @i.n.n.m

Comment: Good @i.n.n.m it will be easier now. Though, no need to yell :)

Comment: why were these omitted? `2017-10-19 06:09:00     1        568.2   1` and `
2017-10-19 06:10:00     1        569     1`

Comment: @scsimon because, my purpose is to take the `min` of `data_from = 1` and check if there is any past 60 mins worth of data in `data_from = 2`. So, the starting point to check for Terminal_ID 1 is `2017-10-19 06:07:00     1        567     1` and for Terminal_ID 9 is `2017-10-19 06:07:00     9        475     1`. Does that explain? I don't know how else to mention my question, I've been Googling, couldn't find something similar to my situation.